# Proportionality constant

Tags: linear-algebra, ratio, arithmetic-progressions, constants

I’ve typed the question, in whose context my doubt is, and it’s answer at the end.

Please note that I do not require the solution as I’ve already understood how to find the answer via the given as well as other methods.

**My actual question is:**

$ 4(p+1)=7q $ and $(p+1)/7=q/4$ are essentially the same equations.

So why don’t we directly do $4(p+1)=7q=k$ , here k is the proportionality constant right?

Why do we get a wrong answer if we use any other form of the equation $(p+1)/7=q/4$ while equating it with k?

For ex:

$4(p+1)=7q$

$4(p+1)/7=q=k$

$p=(7k/4)-1$ and $q=k$

$(7k/4)-1≤102$ and $k≤102$
as p,q≤102

$k≤58.86$ and $k≤102$

$=>k≤58$

which is obviously wrong.

**Question**

Find the number of terms common to the two AP’s: 3,7,11…407 and 2,9,16,..709.

**Answer**

Let number of terms of two AP’s be m and n respectively.

$ 407=3+(m-1)*4$ and $709=2+(n-1)*7$

$=> m=102$ and $n=102 $

Let pth term of first AP and qth term of second AP be identical.

$3+(p-1)*4=2+(q-1)*7$

$4p-1=7q-5$

$4(p+1)=7q$

$(p+1)/7=q/4=k(say)$

$=> p=7k-1 and q=4k
$

As max no. of terms for both AP’s is 102, p,q≤102.

$=>7k-1≤102$ and $4k≤102$

$=>k≤14.71$ and $k≤25.5$

$=> k≤14$ and for each value of k there exists a pair of identical terms.
Hence, there are 14 identical terms.

Comment: Clarifications requested: [1] Are $p$ and $q$ required to be integers?  If so, are they required to be positive integers? [2] "...so why do we get a wrong answer if we do the following:..."?  What is the **right** answer supposed to be, and what answer do you (instead) derive?  Please edit your question to show all of your work.  **Please do not respond with a comment**.  Instead, please edit your question to provide the requested clarifications.  Also, if (then) no one else answers your question, you can leave me a flagging comment (i.e. @user2661923 ...) and I will then re-examine.

Comment: With $q\le 103$ I get $k=q/4\le 25\frac{3}{4}$. This looks greater than $14$. With $p\le 103$ I get $k=(p+1)/7\approx 14.857$.

Comment: Sorry I edited the correct value but also the answers are to be integers so we’d wind up with 14 anyway which is why i didn’t write the fraction part.

Comment: The problem is that you are jumping right into a solution attempt of something. ( Most new contributors are of the other extreme. ) Please give the full background of what you are trying to solve and delete any mention of being "dumb" or not from your post. Looking forward to the new edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > **Question**
> >
> > Find the number of terms common to the two AP’s $$3,7,11,\dots, 407$$
> > and $$2,9,16,\ldots,709.$$
> >
> > **Answer**
>
> > Let number of terms of two AP’s be $m$ and $n$ respectively.
>
> > $$m=102=n.$$
> > Let the $p$th term of the first AP and the $q$th term of the second AP
> > be identical.
> > $$3+4(p-1)=2+7(q-1)\\4p-1=7q-5$$

Hence, we require *the number of integer solutions*, with $$1\leq \;p,q\;\leq102,\tag1$$ of the **Diophantine equation** $$7q-4p=4.\tag{*}$$

By observation<sup>†</sup>, $(p,q)=(6,4)$ is a particular solution. Thus, by [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation), each solution is given by $$(p,q)=(6-7k,4-4k)\quad\text{for some }k\in\mathbb Z.\tag2$$ **Think of $k$ as a counter for the solutions.**

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives $$-13.71\leq k\leq0.71.$$ Thus, there are $14$ integer solutions.

---

<sup>†</sup>Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a,b\in\mathbb Z.$ Then, if (and only if) $b$ is a multiple of $\gcd(a,n),$ $$ax+ny=b$$ has an integer solution $(x,y),$  which can be obtained using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4192333/21813).

Comment: What if we can’t find the possible solution set for p and q by observation?

Comment: @Jasmine I expanded the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The $102$nd term of AP1 is $3+4\cdot101=407$. The $102$nd term of AP2 is $709$. So common terms in these (finite) sequences could have values up to $407$. These common values in the sequences are what your $k$ represents. So values of $k$ could go up as high as $407$.